# How do I run this in a "browser toolbar"?

Tags: javascript, browser, toolbar

I am trying to download a dataset and have been given the line of code below to be quote "run in a browser toolbar on the homepage". However, I have 0 knowledge of javascript and of what a browser toolbar is and what I should even do with the line of code below. I have spent time googling "javascript browser toolbar" and have not found anything remotely helpful. Could someone very kindly provide some assistance?

I changed the letters just to be safe.

```
javascript:(function(){document.cookie="PHPSESSID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";location.reload();})()
```

Answer (score 0):

It called `bookmarklet`.

It helps you run the javascript code without going to use the Console tab. It allows you to always keep your common tasks on a web page just a click away.

You can read this [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/189358/beginner-geek-how-to-use-bookmarklets-on-any-device/) to know how to use it.